# How to have a multiline equation in an array of equations?

Tags: align, amsmath, multline, eqnarray

I am in the situation where I need to define some parameters similar to each other.
For this reason I would like to define them in an `eqnarray` or `align`.
Unfortunately, one of the right hand part of the definitions are overly long for a single line.

Is it possible to use a `multline` or similar inside an `eqnarray` or `align`?

Comment: A general recommendation: **Never** use `eqnarray`. The multi-line display math environments -- such as `align` -- provided by the `amsmath` package are far super to `eqnarray`.

Comment: If you load `mathtools`, you can use `multlined` (within an `align` since it's an extension of amsmath).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked,

> Is it possible to use a `multline` or similar inside an ... `align`?

You can't use a `multline` environment inside an `align` environment. However, it's alright to use `aligned` and `multlined` environments -- the latter requires loading the `mathtools` package -- inside `align` environments.

A minimum working example (MWE):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads "amsmath" automatically
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= b+c \notag \\
  &= \begin{multlined}[t]
     d+e+f+g \\
     +h+i+j+k+l\\
     \shoveright{+m+n+o+p+q+r}
     \end{multlined} \notag \\
  &= s+t+u
\end{align}
\end{document}
```